# ASP.NET Webform: inline code (<%= %> ) vs Server Control Performance?

Tags: asp.net, performance, inline-code

Let's forget about state management, maintenance perspective, etc ... and focus on render performance only

Which of render method has better performance ? <%= ... %> or Server Control (or Html Server Control/ Custom Control/ UserControl) ?

e.g 1: Page1
vs

e.g 2: using <% %> with foreach to render a DataTable
vs
using DataGrid

In my opinion, <% %> will win not only in these 2 examples but also in most cases. As in ASP.NET MVC, we use inline code in Views to render HTML.

What's your opinion ?

Comment: My opinion is that unless you have the worlds biggest webpage, no one will ever notice the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a lot more difficult to manage <% %> code and it tends to be more brittle, IMO.

It might be faster, but you lose maintainability. I have found if it's a data-heavy page, the price of the SQL Query is more expensive than the rendering speed of a GridView or a Repeater.

(That and turning off ViewState.)

Comment: Just to back up the other two commenters, it is almost never the case that your choice of rendering method is going to be your speed bottleneck.